# Placing the where condition

Tags: android, android-emulator, sqlite

I came up with the below query:

```
SELECT ROOMNO,BUILDINGNO 
FROM MRM_ROOM_DETAILS 
WHERE ROOMID IN (
    SELECT distinct roomid 
    FROM MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS 
    WHERE (CHECKIN NOT BETWEEN '2012-04-13 09:50:00' AND '2012-04-13 10:20:00') 
    AND (CHECKOUT NOT BETWEEN '2012-04-13 09:50:00' AND '2012-04-13 10:20:00')) 
AND CAPACITY > 15 
AND PROJECTIONSTATUS = 'NO';
```

I need to place this query in the method SQLiteDatabase.query() and fetch the rows accordingly. I am not able to understand how to place this big where condition (which contains a sub-query as well) in place of the "String selection" i.e. 3rd parameter of the method. Shall i simple write the entire where part(including the sub-query) as a string in the 3rd parameter or else there is some other better way for doing the same?

Please suggest me the best way to do the same.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely use [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) rather than query. What is important here is that you use the `selectionArgs` argument to prevent injection.

```
string sql = "SELECT ROOMNO,BUILDINGNO 
FROM MRM_ROOM_DETAILS 
WHERE ROOMID IN (
    SELECT distinct roomid 
    FROM MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS 
    WHERE (CHECKIN NOT BETWEEN '2012-04-13 09:50:00' AND '2012-04-13 10:20:00') 
    AND (CHECKOUT NOT BETWEEN '2012-04-13 09:50:00' AND '2012-04-13 10:20:00')) 
AND CAPACITY > 15 
AND PROJECTIONSTATUS = 'NO';";
db.rawQuery(sql, null); // <---- here null would be replaced with your 
                        // parameters in order to prevent injection
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you simply supply the complete "where condition" (excluding the "WHERE", including the verbatim subquery) as the `selection` argument to SqliteDatabase.query().

What you need to worry about is *performance*. You don't know in advance what SQLite version you will encounter on your database device, and subqueries are known to sometimes perform rather badly, especially when combined with a LIMIT clause.

Make sure to test this query on a number of devices (unless the amount of rows affected is trivial). You might gain some performance by splitting it up into multiple statements, first simply retrieving the booking details, the getting the room details.

Comment: Do note sixfeetsix' comment about using the selection args. Unless you are sure your arguments are sanitized, injection is something to think about.